# How to publish a message to a Redis Channel (StackExchange.Redis)

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have read an example about subscribing and publishing in StackExchange.Redis documents but I don't understand it.

Why the example doesn't talk about publishing?

```
var channel = multiplexer.GetSubscriber().Subscribe("messages");
channel.OnMessage(message =>
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)message.Message);
});
```

How to implement subscribe and publish in Dotnet Core project?

What is the RedisChannel, Anyone can explain it?

I Do like this:

```
RedisChannel channelWithLiteral = new RedisChannel("messages", RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal);
```

And

```
RedisChannel channelWithLiteral = new RedisChannel("messages", RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal);

var sub = connectionPoolManager.GetConnection().GetSubscriber();
sub.PublishAsync(channelWithLiteral , Serializer.Serialize(message));
```

both Sub and Pub project. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

After adding Redis package to your project (via [StackExchange.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis) NuGet package), you can connect to your Redis server (in this case, local):

```
using StackExchange.Redis;

ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
```

Next, you should subscribe to a channel using the `ISubscriber.Subscribe`:

```
var subscriber = connection.GetSubscriber();
```

Publishing messages to any channel can be done with:

```
subscriber.Publish("channle-name", "This is a message");
```

And finally, subscribing to the same channel (from another client maybe) to receive messages sent over your desired channel:

```
subscriber.Subscribe("channle-name", (channel, message) => {
    Console.WriteLine((string)message);
});
```